# How to access S3 bucket root from CloudFront sub directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

How can I access S3 Root: `/`

from CloudFront sub directory: `https://example.com/foo/` ?

I don't wanna change S3 directory structure (moving `/*` to `/foo/*`)

#### What I've tried

1. Use S3 redirection rules: redirected to S3 static hosting url (not CloudFront)
2. Use CloudFront Lambda Function Associations: when I rewrite `/foo/*` to `/*`, I get what I wanted on `/foo/*` but I must place the same contents on `/*`. (Because it's not routing but url rewriting)

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're asking is possible with CloudFront. I believe that the opposite is possible (have the root of CloudFront distribution serve a subfolder in a S3 bucket), though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying API Gateway now.

Comment: Great! If you find a way to do what you want with API Gateway, could you answer your question with how you achieved it?